# Creating POJO object for every row in recyclerview OnBindViewHolder method

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

Here's my onBindViewHolder method which runs for every row in a recyclerView. I have around 500 to 600 rows at once. What Im doing is 


**1 -** Initializing my Parcelable POJO class object

**2 -** Passing this object as an Intent argument to start another activiy when onItemClick event occurs.

AFAIK the Java doesn't support true closure so, It forces us to make an object/variable final if you want to use it in an inner class. Java imitate closure behavior by storing constant values in hidden variables and refer those later when needed.

What I want to know,

Is It fine in terms of **performance/memory** to create an object for each row in onBinderViewHolder method ?

When these objects get **garbage collected** ?

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Cursor cursor = getItem(position);

        final FF_Task_List task = new FF_Task_List();
        task.setSiteArea(cursor.getString(TaskListEntry.TaskListQuery.SITE_AREA));
        task.setSiteCode(cursor.getString(TaskListEntry.TaskListQuery.SITE_CODE));
        task.setValidOn(cursor.getString(TaskListEntry.TaskListQuery.VALID_ON));
        task.setScore(cursor.getFloat(TaskListEntry.TaskListQuery.SCORE));
        task.setSurveyStatusId(cursor.getInt(TaskListEntry.TaskListQuery.SURVEY_STATUS_ID));
        task.setTokenId(cursor.getLong(TaskListEntry.TaskListQuery.TOKEN_ID));
        task.setEmpId(cursor.getLong(TaskListEntry.TaskListQuery.EMP_ID));
        task.setSurveyTypeId(cursor.getInt(TaskListEntry.TaskListQuery.SURVEY_TYPE_ID));


        final int scoreTextLength = String.valueOf(task.getScore()).length();
        final float score = task.getScore();

        final int scoreColor = Utilities.getColorByStatus(mContext, task.getSurveyStatusId());

        final int statusIcon = Utilities.getIconByStatus(task.getSurveyStatusId());
        final String validOnDate = Utilities.formatDBDate(task.getValidOn(), Utilities.Dates.DISPLAY_DATE);


        sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(task.getScore() + "%");
        sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), scoreTextLength, scoreTextLength + 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);


        holder.siteName.setText(task.getSiteArea());
        holder.siteCode.setText(task.getSiteCode());

        holder.siteInfo.setText(validOnDate);

        holder.siteScore.setTextColor(scoreColor);

        if(score != 0) {
            holder.siteScore.setPadding(5,0,0,0);
            holder.siteScore.setText(sb);
        }else{
            holder.siteScore.setText("--");
        }

        holder.siteScoreProgress.setPercent(score / 100);

        holder.siteStatusIcon.setImageResource(statusIcon);

        holder.taskItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //raise custom itemClick event
                itemClickListener.itemClicked(task ,v);
            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your model stored in a list you will get the value every time you call `getItem(position)` inside the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)`.

The `RecyclerView` controls what are kept in memory at any time and so when you scroll the `RecyclerView` things (views and models) will get garbage collected when it's time for it.

I don't know how many items Android will keep in memory for you at any given time, but it's no more than the items that visible on the screen - and then it might keep a few items outside of view created. On a phone this would usually be 10-15 items, depending on the screensize and item's size.

Then when you scroll back to the same views again, the model will be recreated again and the `ViewHolder` will be updated with the newly created values.

Unless your data model is huge, it shouldn't be a problem creating the objects inside the `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)`.

If you want to avoid creating objects inside the `onBindViewHolder` convert the `Cursor` to your `FF_Task_List` objects and set the list of `FF_Task_List` to your backing model of the `RecyclerView`.